# $\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x^2+9} dx$ with residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate integral
$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{x \sin x}{x^2+9} dx$$
with residue theorem, where we can assume that
$$\int_{\gamma}  \frac{z }{z^2+9} e^{iz} dz \to 0$$ when $r\to \infty$. Where $\gamma$ is parametrization of the upper half of an unit circle.

$$\int_{\gamma}  \frac{z }{(z+3)(z-3)} e^{iz} dz $$

So there is two simple poles at $z_1=-3$ and $z_2 =3$? Do I try to find the residues for the poles and then just use the theorem $2 \pi i \sum B_i$

Comment: The two poles are $\pm 3i$ and only one of them lies inside $\gamma$.

Comment: It's $3i$ right? one the positive half of imaginary axis.

Comment: Yup, you can deform the contour to a small circle around $+3i$ and evaluate the integral by finding the residue at $+3i$.

Comment: The residue at the pole $3i$ is

$$\lim\limits_{z\to 3i} \frac{z}{z+3i} e^{iz} = \frac{3i}{3i+3i} e^{-3} = \frac{1}{2e^3}$$

Comment: Isn't the residue $\frac{1}{2 e^3}$ so the the answer for the integral should be $\frac{i \pi}{e^3}$ but that isnt real...

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+9}\sin x dx
= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+9}\sin x dx
= \frac{1}{2\color{red}{i}}\int_\gamma \frac{z}{z^2+9}e^{iz} dz
= \frac{2\pi i}{2i} \times \frac{1}{2e^3}
= \frac{\pi}{2e^3}$$

Comment: AHh! Yes! Now I got it! if you want points for that answer feel free to post it and I'll accept it :)

Comment: actually I don't want the points. You can post your own answer and accept it.